# Ritual Hex vs Take 10 / Take 20

Tags: pathfinder-1e, witch

I want to be sure before I take it:
https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/ritual-hex/

...are those your good old regular Knowledge Checks? Does this mean I can use Take 10 / Take 20 to guarantee a success 100% of the time?

I'm most interested in take 10, the take 20 part of the question is more for future people looking for similar thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No: You cannot Take 10/20 on Occult Rituals

The [Ritual Hex feat](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Ritual%20Hex) gives you the knowledge of a special occult ritual:

> You learn to perform a special occult ritual known as Beseeching the
> Patron

And Occult Rituals are subject to a set of rules, that explicitly state you are neither allowed to Take 10 nor Take 20 on the associated skill checks:

> [Casting Occult Rituals](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Casting%20Occult%20Rituals&Category=Occult%20Rituals)
>
> One of the casters—either the primary caster or a secondary caster who
> the primary caster specifies— attempts one of the skill checks
> required by the ritual every 10 minutes of the casting, unless the
> ritual takes 1 hour per caster level, in which case the caster
> attempts the check every hour of the ritual. These checks cannot
> benefit from the aid another action, and the caster attempting the
> check **can’t take 10 or take 20**, even if she has an ability that would
> normally allow her to do so when threatened or distracted.

Comment: Note: This is the same source of reference as the other answer by @Ifusaso, though I don't know why he came to the opposite conclusion (and neither do the other commenters, it seems). If he intends to change his answer, mine can be deleted.

Comment: Reading too quickly. Thanks for posting the correct answer